# Have tried all traditional troubleshooting: "Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script..."

Tags: vbscript

I've done all the traditional fixes in every major threads related to this problem and I still get this error. I'm trying to run a .vbs to install a webdisk onto my computer. (Please note that I'm not a programmer so I'm hoping to receive help in Layman's terms.)

I've gone into registry and fixed the HKEY to list the .dll.
I've deleted all cleaners and adblockers and anti-virus programs.
I've created a new .reg that merged threads.

Please help. I'm going crazy up here at the lake.

Cheers.

Comment: Try typing in a command prompt `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` and `%windir%\syswow64\regsvr32 vbscript.dll`

Comment: Isn't this more a [su] question?

Comment: What kind of Antivirus did you have installed or uninstalled ?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:

1. Open command prompt as Administrator using `Run As Administrator`
2. Now type `sfc /scannow` and press enter.
3. Check the message that you get and take the corresponding action as mentioned [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

You can also try doing the following:

1. Run `regsvr32 vbscript.dll` and `regsvr32 jscript.dll` in command prompt as administrator.
2. Also run the `Windows Cleanup Utility` as Administrator.

This should fix your issue.